# phpMyAdmin giving error #1064 when trying to insert ID(using SET IDENTITY_INSERT) into table

Tags: mysql, sql

so I have a problem with a mySQL database I was given and am supposed to put on phpMyAdmin. Here are the tables that are causing an issue.

```
/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: ContributionState                                     */
/*==============================================================*/
create table ContributionState
(
   ContributionStateID  int not null auto_increment,
   Title                national varchar(100) not null,
   DisplayOrder         int not null,
   primary key (ContributionStateID)
);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT ContributionState ON
INSERT INTO ContributionState(ContributionStateID,Title,DisplayOrder) 
VALUES (1,N'Vote up',1),
(2,N'Vote Down',2),
(3,N'Vulgar',3),
(4,N'Spam',4),
(5,N'Accepted',5),
(6,N'Rejected',6),
(7,N'Live',7)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ContributionState OFF

/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: Contribution_States                                   */
/*==============================================================*/
create table Contribution_States
(
   Contribution_StatesID int not null auto_increment,
   ContributionStateID  int not null,
   ContributionID       int not null,
   UserID               int not null,
   CreatedDate          datetime not null default 'getdate()',
   primary key (Contribution_StatesID)
);

/*==============================================================*/
/* Index: INDEX_1                                               */
/*==============================================================*/
create unique index INDEX_1 on Contribution_States
(
   ContributionStateID,
   ContributionID,
   UserID
);
```

The problem that I am facing is that phpMyAdmin is returning error #1064(meaning that there is an error with the syntax) near 'ContributionState ON Insert ...'. I don't know what to fix for it to run properly as I am a beginner in mySQL and would appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are three separate queries. You need to separate them with semi-colons.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ContributionState ON;
INSERT INTO ContributionState(ContributionStateID,Title,DisplayOrder) 
VALUES (1,N'Vote up',1),
(2,N'Vote Down',2),
(3,N'Vulgar',3),
(4,N'Spam',4),
(5,N'Accepted',5),
(6,N'Rejected',6),
(7,N'Live',7);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ContributionState OFF;
```

Comment: I changed my code and added the semicolons as you said. It certainly caused some progress(Thank you for the help) and narrowed the error message. Now the error message is like this:                                            
SQL query:                     


SET IDENTITY_INSERT ContributionState ON
MySQL said: 


#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ContributionState ON' at line 1


If you know why this error is happening, please help.

Comment: I'm not familiar `IDENTITY_INSERT ContributionState`. The `set` command usually sets a variable or setting. e.g. `set @name = 'chris';`. That actually looks like sql-server, try commenting it out.